# How to make href listen stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

stopPropagation works but cannot stop href being executed on child click, is there a way to make parent anchor do not execute it's href on child element is clicked(stopPropagation/bubbling)?

**Here is my markup:**

```
<div id="parent">
  <h5>Parent</h5>
  <a id="childAnchor" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
    <h5>Child anchor tag</h5>

    <div id="grandChildAnchor">
      <h5>Grand Child div tag</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is jsfiddle where I am redirecting on anchor click: https://jsfiddle.net/gchc9Ldb/

Here is stackoverflow code snippet but the redirect (target="_blank") is not happening correctly. So check the above jsfiddle link rather below code snippet.

```js
$('#parent').click(function() {
  console.log('#parent clicked');
})

$('#parent a').click(function() {
  console.log('#parent > anchor clicked');
})

$('#parent a div').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('#parent > anchor > clicked');
})
```

```css
h5 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 50px 10px;
  background-color: blue
}

#grandChildAnchor {
  padding: 25px 0;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <h5>Parent</h5>
  <a id="childAnchor" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
    <h5>Child anchor tag</h5>
    
    <div id="grandChildAnchor">
      <h5>Grand Child div tag</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
I don't want to run `return false` on my anchor tag's href, I still need href to work but not when the anchor tag's child is clicked. `e.stopPropagation` will not work for me. Hence, it's not a duplicate question as most assumed.

Comment: that said I don't really understand your question. What you want is not clear to me

Comment: @Liam you read my **Edit**, may be it explains more to you to unmark it as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `e.preventDefault();`

```
$('#parent a div').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('#parent > anchor > clicked');
})
```

`e.stopPropagation()` stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.

`e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action the browser makes on that event

Here is the working link to [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gchc9Ldb/1/)

Comment: How will it work as OP is using e.stopPropagation()

Comment: But when you use e.stopPropagation() it works in fiddle as well

Comment: Apparently my understanding on this is just wrong. I can replicate the scenario locally from scratch (taking jQuery out of the equation just in case) and preventing the default works and stopping propagation doesn't. I was certain if you didn't let it propagate to the `a`, the default behavior wouldn't be triggered, but the evidence says otherwise. TIL I guess.

Comment: @AKA `e.preventDefault()` helped, thanks. As you got to understand my question, you may agree it's not a duplicate question, I don't want to run `return false` on my anchor tag's href, it still need href to work but not when the anchor's child is clicked. Hope my question deserve up vote rather down vote :)

Comment: @Syed i understood that that is why i upvote your answer. Do not know why people are so eager to mark the question as duplicate.